# Comparar Datas - PHP - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, tenho o seguinte caso estou com uma data no banco de dados salvando assim:
**(02-12-2016)**. A ideia seria pegar a data atual e caso ela seja menor que 2 dias que a data citada acima faça tal coisa. Eu tentei fazer assim:

```
        foreach ($teste as $row) {
        $data_validade = $row->data_validade;
        echo $data_validade;
        $data_atual = date('d-m-Y');
        $diferenca = strtotime($data_validade) - strtotime($data_atual);
        $dias = floor($diferenca / (60 * 60 * 24));

        if ($dias < 2) {
            redirect('Painel_voluntario/index/?aviso=4');
        } else {
            $dados['status_vaga'] = 'Voluntário Desistiu...';
            $data = array(
                "excluir" => $this->Vaga_model->aceitarOuRecusar($id_vaga, $id_voluntario, $dados)
            );
            redirect('Painel_voluntario/index/?aviso=3');
        }

    }
```

Neste caso até está funcionando, mas por exemplo se eu digito uma data muito alta como **29-10-2998**, não vai funcionar(está caindo no if que ele é menor que dois dias, o que logo está errado).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
foreach ($teste as $row) {
    $data_validade = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row->data_validade));
    echo $data_validade;
    $data_atual = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
    $diferenca = $data_validade->diff($data_atual);

    $dias = $diferenca->format('%a');
    $op = $diferenca->format('%R');

    if ($op == "-" && $dias > 2) {
        redirect('Painel_voluntario/index/?aviso=4');
    } else {
        $dados['status_vaga'] = 'Voluntário Desistiu...';
        $data = array(
            "excluir" => $this->Vaga_model->aceitarOuRecusar($id_vaga, $id_voluntario, $dados)
        );
        redirect('Painel_voluntario/index/?aviso=3');
    }

}
```